# Accessing stylesheet asset inside a rails 2.3 gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to place stylesheet assets when building a gem for

```
rails 2.3.18
```

I have already tried creating `vendor/stylesheets/custom_style.css` inside the gem 
I also tried `public/stylesheets/custom_style.css`

but there is no way to access it also how do we dynamically declare the stylesheet without touching `application_layout.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

Just include `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "custom_style" %>` given that its located anywhere in the following: app/assets, lib/assets or vendor/assets, then inspect your  on browser console to make sure its being included.